# asp.net calendar

Tags: asp.net, calendar

How can I add asp:panel inside Calendar1_DayRender e.Cells so that when there are many items in the lists it would make that cells scrollable instead of stretching the calendar.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    div.ID = "div1";
    div.Attributes["style"] = "overflow:auto; width:100%; height:100%; ";

    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
    temp.Append("<br />");
    temp.Append("text");

    div.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(temp.ToString()));
    e.Cell.Controls.Add(div);
```

}

I've solved my problem using the code above.
Thank You.